# Read route params inside class component

Tags: react-native

What I'm struggling to do is read route params inside a 'class extends React.Component'.

I have a page built like this, and it works fine (because it is as const and I can put the {route}):

```
const SecondPage = ({route}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://myurl', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        aula: route.params.paramKey //HERE WORKS FINE
      })
    }) ...
```

But in another page, that looks like the code bellow, I have NO IDEA of how I can read a param passed from the previous screen inside it

```
class Newpage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isFetching: false,
      isLoading: null,
      tooltipPos: { x: 0, y: 0, visible: false, value: 0 },
      data: {
        labels: ["", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
            }
        ]
    }
    };
  }

  getApiData() {
    const self = this;
    fetch('https://anotherurl', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        param: passedParam //HERE I NEED TO HAVE THE PASSED PARAM
      })
    }) ...
```

This is my First page where I'm passing the param:

```
renderButtons = () => {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return (
      <Block flex>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Newpage", {
              idLancamento: item.id,
            })}>
```

Comment: you can access it using this.props anywhere in class component. in constructor you have to use props. it will have navigation nested object with all values you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on if your Newpage class component is a screen component inside the navigation container.

If it is, then you simply access it using `this.props.route`.

If it is not, then you will need to pass the `route` from the caller.

For example, you have a screen component called `Parent`, that renders the `NewPage` component. You will need to pass the `route` prop like so:

```
    <Newpage route={this.props.route} /> //assuming the Parent is a class.
```

to read the params you can do the following:

```
const { idLancamento } = this.props.route.params;

getApiData() {
    const self = this;
    fetch('https://anotherurl', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        param: idLancamento //this is the same of the param passed from navigate call 
      })
    }) ...
```

Comment: Hi! So, I'm not sure of how can I read the param inside my Fetch Call with your code. `body: JSON.stringify({
        param: passedParam //HERE I NEED TO HAVE THE PASSED PARAM
      })`

Comment: Thank you so much for you patience with my question. I added 'this.props.route' inside my fetch to see what is being sent, and just realized that my param 'idLancamento' was not there. So, if I'm not wrong, this is because I'm not passing or getting the param properly. I saw your explanation about passing the route from the caller, but my current code is:
class extends { ... getApi () ... buttons = () => { code ... and in the end: render() { return ( {buttons()}.

Comment: your parameter `idLancamento` should be in `this.props.route.params` if everything else works as expected.

Comment: I just figured it out something that was wrong. I was using different stacks. Inserted the two pages in the same stack and everything is working PERFECT. Thank you SO much. Your code is working perfectly. Thank you 1M times!!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `'@react-navigation/native';`

```
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';   

//pass the params
const navigation = useNavigation();
navigation.navigate('screenname', {userId: 1});


//get the params 
import {useRoute} from '@react-navigation/native';

// it will return userId
 getRouterParams(){
   const route = useRoute();
   const params= route.params.userId;
   console.log(params);
   return params;
}

  this.getRouterParams();
```

Comment: I tried to change my code to your directions, but the “ const navigation = useNavigation();” returned the error “invalid hook call”. Just added my first screen code as it is right now in my question

Comment: have you installed `@react-navigation/native` npm package?

Comment: Yes! And thank you so much for your answer! But I've figured it out with Wen's answer!